# UIBarbuttonItem change the textColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I have these two buttons in a toolBar and wants to change the color of UIBarButtons how can i do such a thing? i've tried setTitleTextAttributes, but it does not seem like it has a object with that? How can i do this

```
UIBarButtonItem *sysDoneButton = [self createButtonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self
                                                         action:@selector(actionPickerDone:)];

UIBarButtonItem *sysCancelButton = [self createButtonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self
                                                           action:@selector(actionPickerCancel:)];
```

Comment: The syntax in your example is Objective-C, and the example shows nothing about a color. But creating a UIBarButtonItem and linking it to a selector. I am not sure if you are asking how to convert the above code to Swift. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sry trying to do it in objetive-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UIBarButtonItem's color is its `tintColor`. (Or it can use the `tintColor` inherited from the toolbar you put it into.)

Comment: tintColor did not work? could that be because i already applied a color for all in appDelegate?

Comment: tintColor did not work. i Also tried [navigation.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]]; But no luck at all.
is it because i applied for all navigation item color in appDelegate ?

Comment: @OceanBlue don't leech in the comments; ask a new _question_

Answer (score 0):

It seems UIBarButtonItems won't change it's tint color once they are added to the navigation bar.

What I did was to create a new one instead with new attributes.

```
let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(someAction))
rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.white
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
```