# Changing font color of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor

I tried to change the font color of the right bar button item to purple, but it still shows up as white. I've consulted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917055/uibarbuttonitem-change-the-textcolor) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602794/how-to-change-tintcolor-of-uibarbuttonitem-swift). How do I fix this?

**Code**

```
let sortButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 15))
    sortButton.setTitle("SORT", for: .normal)
    sortButton.titleLabel?.tintColor = UIColor.myMusicPurple
    sortButton.tintColor = UIColor.myMusicPurple        
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(customView: sortButton)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.myMusicPurple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using:

```
func setTitleColor(UIColor?, for: UIControlState)
```

Documentation says it sets the color of the title to use for the specified state.

```
sortButton.setTitleColor( .red, for: .normal)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have `setTitleColor`. The correct answer is to use `tintColor`.

Answer (score 36):

This should do the trick (if you have plain text)

```
let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Some text", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(someAction))
rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.myMusicPurple

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 10):

Please try this

```
sortButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 7):

Its simple, just create a reference for UIBarButtonItem from Main.stroyboard to corresponding swift file like this,

```
@IBOutlet var yourBarBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
```

After that write this line,

```
yourBarBtn.tintColor = .white //your_color
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to set plain properties then after you can write as like.

[image]

```
  @IBOutlet weak var btnGenerate: UIBarButtonItem!

  btnGenerate.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.colorBlue], for: .normal)
```