# Unable to change the color of UIBarItem programmatically swift

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am unable to change the color of UIBarItem programmatically swift. I want to change the color of this "create" button whether something happens. But nothing changes the color of the button.

Here is an image of the button :

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing font color of UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893174/changing-font-color-of-uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: I already did what Hasan can said.

Comment: Which is why I asked you post to your code, so we can see what you have already tried, or see if there is a problem with your code.  See: How to create a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, but I tried the things in page you shared and it didn't work. Can I share a GitHub repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how You can achieve it programatically in `viewDidLoad` add this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


      let butt =   createButton.customView as? UIButton
        butt?.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please try ***tintColor*** attribute

```
let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Text", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(objcAction))

rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.red

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
```

Comment: I tried it it is not working !

Comment: Please show what you have tried.